# How to add additional jar file to spring-boot application at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I built a spring-boot application and make the jar file exectuable. There is a `compileOnly` dependency on my project which need to be provided at runtime. When I run `java -jar myApp.jar` I will get ClassNotFound exeception which is expected. But I don't know how to add the additional jar file on `java` command. I have tried below command:

```
java -Dloader.path=/libs/third.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

but it doesn't work. How can I add `/libs/third.jar` on my application?

Answer (score 1):

On Unix:
`java -cp MyApp.jar:./libs/third.jar com.packagename.MainClass`

On Windows: use `;` instead of `:` and also `\` instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I figured out the problem with `-Dloader.path`. In order to make it works I need to change the project layout to be `ZIP` which will use `PropertiesLauncher`. Below is the configuration.

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
    layout = "ZIP"
}
```